# How to parse two specific information from the result of ls -l as arguments by using the scanf function?

Tags: c, scanf, ls

```
someuser:~/repo/a1/part1> /bin/ls -l
total 12
-rw------- 1 someuser student  489 Jan 28 07:30 file.c
-rw------- 1 someuser student  462 Jan 16 12:44 Make
drwx------ 2 someuser student 4096 Jan 28 03:59 test_inputs
```

Take the second line in the result for example.

`-rw------- 1 someuser student  489 Jan 28 07:30 file.c`

I want to parse the permission`-rw-------` and file size`489` as arguments in another function via the `scanf` function. How can I implement it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have an [mcve] of your attempt? How does it work, or how doesn't it work?

Comment: What I can do so far is only exclude the first line, which is `total 12` from the result and go through the whole line to get the arguments that I want. But this looks dumb. I'm wondering if I can get those information by index something like that.

Comment: A more idiomatic solution would be to use [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/readdir.html)

Comment: Yea, I prefer not to use `scanf`. But it is required.

Comment: Simple solution: [Read a line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) into a string, parse that string (using `sscanf`) to extract the two value you need. Use the assignment-suppressing character `*` to skip the data between the permissions and the size. And read the permissions as a single string (to be further parsed later). The data after the size you don't need format specifiers for, it will just be ignored.

Comment: The `scanf` is required. That's too bad. As @pete has observed, the idiomatic way would be `readdir`. Also (if `scanf` were not required), see the POSIX library function `stat`, exposed by <unistd.h>.

Answer (score 0):

> Use fgets()

Read the *line* and then parse it. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54403359/how-to-parse-two-specific-information-from-the-result-of-ls-l-as-arguments-by-u/54405087#comment95617568_54403359)

The "scanf.... is required" is a bad requirement.  But sometimes out customers are - well - somewhat foolish.

> using the scanf function

The key is that the entire line  needs to be parsed to align input for the next parsing.

A fairly simply approach is to use:

- `"*"` to scan per the specifier, but not save.
- Look for the final `'\n'` or end-of-file.

[scanf() details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string)

```
// -rw------- 1 someuser student  489 Jan 28 07:30 file.c

char rights[10+1];
unsigned long long size;
int count;
for (;;) {
  char eol = '\n';
  count = scanf("%10s %*d %*s %*s %llu %*s %*d %*d:%*d %*s%c", rights, &size, &eol);
  if (count == EOF) break;
  if (count >= 2 && eol == '\n') {
    printf("Rights:<%s> size:%llu\n", rights, size);
  } else {
    // input ill formed, handle error
    // Perhaps report error, then read and toss, up to the end-of-line
    TBD();
  }
}
```